# Is there a way to add up integers which i have retrieved from a .txt file

Tags: python, csv

I have tried to add them up from each line however it does not work

```
import csv

FILE_NAME = "paintingJobs.txt" #I use this so that the file can be used easier
COL_HEADERS = ['Number', 'Date', 'ID', 'Total', 'Status', 'Paid']
NUM_COLS = len(COL_HEADERS)#This will insure that the header of each column fits into the length of the data

# read file once to determine maximum width of data in columns
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # determine the maximum width of the data in each column
    max_col_widths = [len(col_header) for col_header in COL_HEADERS]
    for columns in reader:
        for i, col in enumerate(columns):
            if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
                max_col_widths[i] = max(max_col_widths[i], len(repr(col)))
    # add 1 to each for commas
    max_col_widths = [col_width+1 for col_width in max_col_widths]

# read file second time to display its contents with the headers
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # display justified column headers
    print(' ' + ' '.join(col_header.ljust(max_col_widths[i])
                            for i, col_header in enumerate(COL_HEADERS)))
    # display justified column data
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
            print ("Amount_Outstanding:"),
            print (int(columns[3]) - int(columns[5])),
```

This is the outcome:

```
Number   Date          ID      Total   Status  Paid  
['E5345', '22/09/2015', 'C106', '815', 'A', '400']
Amount_Outstanding:
415
['E5348', '23/09/2015', 'C109', '370', 'A', '200']
Amount_Outstanding:
170
['E5349', '25/09/2015', 'C110', '480', 'A', '250']
Amount_Outstanding:
230
['E5353', '28/09/2015', 'C114', '272', 'A', '200']
Amount_Outstanding:
72
['E5355', '29/09/2015', 'C116', '530', 'A', '450']
Amount_Outstanding:
80
['E5363', '01/10/2015', 'C124', '930', 'A', '500']
Amount_Outstanding:
430
['E5364', '02/10/2015', 'C125', '915', 'A', '800']
Amount_Outstanding:
115
['E5367', '03/10/2015', 'C128', '427', 'A', '350']
Amount_Outstanding:
77
['E5373', '10/10/2015', 'C134', '1023', 'A', '550']
Amount_Outstanding:
473
```

So I was wondering if I could add up the total of each Amount_Outstanding and change it to a different variable, bare in mind I'm new to python and csv

Comment: Why not store the amount outstanding in a list? That way, you can sum them all up, and also access them individually if needed.

Comment: So how would I start about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by creating a 'outstanding_amount' list where you can put in it all the outstanding amounts and win :D

```
#build the list
outstanding_amount = []

# read file second time to display its contents with the headers
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # display justified column headers
    print(' ' + ' '.join(col_header.ljust(max_col_widths[i])
                            for i, col_header in enumerate(COL_HEADERS)))
    # display justified column data
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
            print ("Amount_Outstanding:")
            print (int(columns[3]) - int(columns[5]))

            ###### NEW PART ######
            outstanding_amount.append(int(columns[3]) - int(columns[5]))

# Show the sum of all collected outstanding amount
print (sum(outstanding_amount))
```

You can even access the data set by doing something like this.

For example, if you want to know the outstanding amount for the 2nd item. Then you do:

```
print outstanding_amount[1] # Since we start from 0, the second item is at index 1
```

Comment: Thank you i have been stuck for ages. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NigelHarrison No worries!

Comment: @NigelHarrison Ask away :)

Comment: @Adib could you possibly help me with another error

Comment: Ok i will change the text above to my problem now

Comment: @NigelHarrison Don't do that, let's chat :)

Comment: Actually, now I'm curious where I can start chat from here D:

Comment: I have printed it but i can start a chat if you want.

Comment: Because of this: `total_revenue.append(int(columns[3]) == int(columns[5]))`. Instead of minus, you used equal

Comment: Yes as this time i want to add up costs which are the same  however it is adding up 1 each time

Comment: @NigelHarrison I'm confused. Your statement  has `==`, and what that does is literally give the answer `True` or `False`. `True` is also represented as 1. So, if there are ten `True`'s then that's ten 1's, which has the total sum of 10. I guess you wanted to make it `int(columns[3]) - int(columns[5])`?

Comment: @Adib No i wanted to make sure that if both columns are equal

Comment: @Adib should i use the singular =

Comment: Going to spam so I get prompted a chat. One second

Comment: @NigelHarrison No, you don't need to use singular =. That will assign the value to something else, and that's definitely not what you want to do

Comment: @NigelHarrison You already checked for 'equivalence' with the 'if' statement. Then why do you want to add the equivalence in the append? That makes no sense

Comment: Because i want to get the total cost of each one and assign it to a variable

Comment: @NigelHarrison try doing this so you can see what happens `print int(columns[3]) == int(columns[5])`

Comment: @NigelHarrison My problem is this part: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fa3ltmna4pp93rr/Screenshot%202016-04-13%2018.39.49.png?dl=0 Where you have done your if condition, and you're appending "True" or "False" instead of the number

Comment: Its an invalid syntax

Comment: How do i append the number then?

Comment: @NigelHarrison `list.append(number)` .... something like this `total_revenue.append(int(columns[3]))`

Comment: @NigelHarrison Please practice often. Based on the questions you've asked, it would help to understand the basics of Python. Have you tried codeacademy?

Comment: @Adib A bit of code academy but i seem to learn quite well through experience however i feel like I need to work on the basic still

Comment: @Adib So thank you for all of the help and i wish you the best. :)

Comment: @NigelHarrison Most welcome! Glad I could be of help!